# How to compute connected-component using Python Client in Grakn

Tags: python, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I want to get clusters(or connected components) using Python client. I can do it with graql with following:

`compute cluster in [company, c2c], using connected-component, where contains=V86179944;`

I can run the query with Python as well:

```py
query = "compute cluster in [company, c2c], using connected-component, where contains=V86179944;"
with GraknClient(uri="localhost:48555") as client:
    with client.session(keyspace=keyspace) as session:
        with session.transaction().read() as transaction:
            answer_iterator = transaction.query(query)
            # What to do here??
```

However, **I don't know how to access the results**. According to [python client docs](https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/client-api/python), there are 2 ways of getting results:

- iterate over
- use `collect_concepts()`

When I iterate over, I can't use `.map()` I get `AttributeError: 'ConceptSet' object has no attribute 'map'`

When I try `collect_concepts`, I get `GraknError: Only use .collect_concepts on ConceptMaps returned by query()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` and `collect_concepts` (which will be [removed](https://github.com/graknlabs/client-python/commit/bb2e292ad5c8098a9941081d8aab80c1c64bf822) in the next release of Client Python) are methods of the `ConceptMap` answer type. What you're getting back as the result of a `compute cluster` query is the `ConceptSet` answer type. `ConceptSet` has the `set()` method that returns the set of ids of concepts after the cluster computation.

[Here](http://dev.grakn.ai/docs/client-api/python#answer) you'll find the query types and their corresponding answer type and [here](http://dev.grakn.ai/docs/client-api/python#conceptset) you'll find the documentation on the `set()` method available on a `ConceptSet`.

Comment: Both of the hyperlinks( _here_ s) in second paragraph are same URL. Is it intended?

Comment: @kvtoraman updated the second link. thanks for letting me know :)